# Как получить текст из элемента div или т.п.?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, веб-программирование

html:

```
<div id="txt_id">text</div>
```

js:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("txt_id").textContent;
console.log(elem)
```

ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: подправил оформление.. и.. заработало(

Comment: Удалите вопрос...не имеет смысла вопрос на который нету ответа, или сами себе ответьте

Comment: а как ты скрипт подключаешь, вероятно он запрашивает элемент до его отрисовки
код выполняется построчно, если ты сразу после body вставишь скрипт до разметки сначала выполнится этот скрипт а потом будут оnрисовываться элементы страницы, поэтому если в скрипте ты получаешь доступ к элементу который ещё не отрисован тебе вернётся null, ставь тег скрипта после разметки перед закрывающим тегом body

Comment: jour а где ты и что подправил?

Comment: `Спасибо за предложенную правку. Она будет видна только вам до тех пор, пока не будет одобрена проверенными участниками сообщества.` ждемс ответ

Comment: jour а у меня не работает

Comment: @Jour, ошибка в вопросе явна вызвана не из-за кода, а из-за того, как подключен JS скрипт. Ваша правка в данном случае не уместна.

Comment: @OliverPatterson в этом и ответ) хз как у него подключено

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = document.getElementById("getSSS");
var innerHTML = a.innerHTML;
var outerText = a.outerText;
console.log('innerHTML: ' + innerHTML);
console.log('outerText: ' + outerText);
```

```css
.out-block {
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="getSSS">
  <p>Тест в параграфе</p>
  NodeText
  <div>
    <b>Жирный текст в диве</b>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="out-block">
  <div id="out1"></div>
  <div id="out2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Вообще это делается через innerHTML...

```
var elem = document.getElementById("txt_id");

console.log(elem.innerHTML);
```